# Fragment with two layouts

Tags: android, service, fragment

I have a consultation with the subject of fragments and hope I can help me, I have created two layouts I use to control the orientation (Portrait and Landscape) and both call the same class Fragment.
When I'm running some routine in an orientation (portrait) is ok, but when change occurs orientation, the objects are "restarted" or "regenerate", I read that this could be corrected with validating the generated instance with savedInstanceState(), but appreciate your help

Greetings.

PS: Sorry for my english

```
public class AlbumDetail extends Activity {

....

private Bundle bundle = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.bundle = savedInstanceState;
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.albumdetail_p);
        initUI();            
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.albumdetail_l);
        initUI();            
    }


    lstSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                pos = position;
                if (bundle == null){
                  PlayFragment fragment = (PlayFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlay);
                  if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
                     fragment.getPlaySong(pos,isRandom,songs);
                  }
                }
            }
    });
}       

private void initUI(){                
    /* Initialize variables */        
}        
}


public class PlayFragment extends Fragment{

private Intent playIntent;
private View view;

....... //Variables

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentplay, container, false);        
    return view;
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);        
}    

public void initUI(){
    /* Initialize variables*/
}

public void getPlaySong(int position, boolean isRandom, Object lstSong) {
    initUI();
    try {
        playIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), PlaySongServiceFragment.class);
        playIntent.putExtra("pos", position);
        playIntent.putExtra("rnd", isRandom);
        playIntent.putExtra("list", (Serializable) lstSong);
        getActivity().startService(playIntent);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way to do this. Especially if you are using all the same children in the layout (the fragment).

Put the portrait layout in the `layout` folder. Put the landscape layout, WITH THE SAME NAME AS THE PORTRAIT ONE, in the `layout-land` folder. Make sure all the children in the layouts have the same id as well (if you're using the same or similar children).

Then you can just handle it in your `Activity` as if it's just a single layout and let the device choose which one to use.